# How to attach invoice pdf with invoice email

Tags: magento2.3, email, invoice, pdf, invoice-pdf

I would like to attach the invoice PDF to the invoice email. I have searched through several links on Stack Exchange, but unfortunately, I have not been able to make any progress on this issue.

I am aware that customers can download their invoices from their account area. However, I am wondering if there is a way to automatically attach the customer's invoice to the invoice email that we send out.

I hope someone can guide me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can also take a look at an existing extension: https://fooman.com/magento-extension-email-attachments-m2.html. This extension is used very often and Fooman extensions are of high quality.
I would give this a try.

Comment: This module doesn’t work when you run setup:di:compile

Comment: I honestly think you should try giving this extension another shot. They have a demo of it on their page so it most definitely does work. Maybe take a look at this install guide and maybe it might work for you: https://magento2-support.fooman.co.nz/article/1288-installing-email-attachments-m2-from-fooman-website

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `createAttachement` of `Zend_Mail` class. Your message should inherit this class. If you get the message from your transport class and add the attachement there it should work.

I would propose the following code - the creation of the invoice pdf is tested and safe, the rest is theoretical :-). Of course it might be usefull to transfer the object creation into constructor and add some error handling.

```
public function sendMail($emailTemplateVariables,$senderInfo,$receiverInfo,$type,$invoiceId = null)
{
    [...]
    $this->generateTemplate($emailTemplateVariables,$senderInfo,$receiverInfo);
    $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->getTransport();
    //attach the invoice pdf
    $this->attachInvoicePdf($invoiceId);
    $transport->sendMessage();
    $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
}

private function attachInvoicePdf($invoiceId){

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $pdfInvoiceModel = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice');
    $invoice = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice')->load($invoiceId);
    $pdfContent = $pdfInvoiceModel->getPdf([$invoice])->render();
    $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->getTransport();
    $transport->getMessage()->createAttachment($pdfContent);
    
}
```

Comment: Can you show me a example I don’t get what you meant by create a method of createAttachment. Am I creating a plugin for this

Comment: It looks like he is showing an example. Looks as to be the `attachInvoicePdf()` function is good to go. The `sendMail()` function is where you would need to come up with the `[...]` to make it work for your store. This code would most likely have to be put in a custom/local extension.